# Swift how to find an object in array of AnyObject

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to get the Index of current ViewController in my NavigationController.

The problem is that navigationController.viewControllers is of type AnyObject, now i get the error Cannot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type (AnyObject, UIViewController).

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    var index = find(navigationController.viewControllers, viewController)
}
```

How can i fix this, how do i get the Index in an AnyObject array?

Comment: Does "current view controller" mean top view controller?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because `find` function doesn't know how to compare `AnyObject` with `UIViewViewController`. Even though `navigationController.viewControllers`'s `[AnyObjects]` array shouldn't contain anything but `UIViewController` instances, compiler doesn't know that. We can help it by casting the array (using `as!`) to `[UIViewController]`.

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    var index = find(navigationController.viewControllers as! [UIViewController], viewController)
}
```